# How to stop a program from storing more than a single character into a char variable?

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

My program uses a scanf as such:

```
scanf ("%c", &symbol);
```

is there a way to print an error if the user enters in a string > one character? e.g "abc" as it messes with the program later on

Comment: There is not "a" way to do this. There are plenty. One of them is to see if there is further input with `getchar()` or something similar (to consume any invalid input). Or just scan a characters sequence with `%s` and then pick the first one. There are so many options, it's hard to tell what would be the best for you without some more context.

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't use `scanf` in the first place. It's a buffer overflow waiting to happen.

Comment: @chepner, reading *one* character into a `char` variable using `scanf(3)` can't possibly cause a buffer overrun.

Comment: @vonbrand: Let's play a game: how long has it been since I've programmed in anything more low level than Python? :) I forgot the format string will control how much is read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string buffer, fgets() into it, check if the second character is a `\n`.